# Silex, mount multiple controller providers with closures

Tags: closures, silex

I'm trying out Silex and I'm having a bit of a problem, or I might say, more of an inconvenience...

I'm trying to load 2 routes from 2 separate yaml files, but for some reason the mounting (`$app->mount(...)`) doesn't work with closures.

Here's some code:

```
// load configuration
$loader->load('core.yml');
$loader->load('api.yml');


function bla($app, $container, $key) {
    $myApp = $app['controllers_factory'];

    foreach ($container->getExtensionConfig('routes')[$key] as $name => $route) {
        $controller = $myApp->match($route['pattern'], $route['controller']);
        $controller->method($route['requirements']['_method']);
        $controller->bind($name);
    }
    return $myApp;
}

$app->mount('/core', bla($app, $container, 0));
$app->mount('/api', bla($app, $container, 1));
```

This works.

What doesn't work is if I do the exact same thing with closures, like this:

```
$app->mount('/core', function ($app, $container, $key) {
    return $app['controllers_factory'];
});
```

Gives the following error:

```
LogicException: The "mount" method takes either a ControllerCollection or a ControllerProviderInterface instance.
```

But

```
var_dump($app['controllers_factory']);
```

spits out an object of type `Silex\ControllerCollection`.

I'm obviously missing something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## The problem

In your first example, you're mounting the result of a function. In your second example, you're mounting the function itself.

Function `bla()` returns the controller collection when it's called. When you do

```
$app->mount('/core', bla($app, $container, 0));
```

the function is executed first and then the returned `ControllerCollection` is mounted.

But when you do

```
$app->mount('/core', function ($app, $container, $key) {...});
```

the function is not executed. It is treated as an object and mounted. Since the function itstelf is not a `ControllerCollection` or a `ControllerProviderInterface`, you get the error.

## Two alternatives

### Use PHP routing

This is how I like to do it. I don't know if this is "the Silex way", but it works well for me.

You mount each controller collection like so:

```
$app->mount('/core', include 'controllers/core.php');
$app->mount('/api', include 'controllers/api.php');
```

Each controller collection goes in a separate file in the `controllers` folder. So api.php might look like this:

```
$controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

$controllers->get('/version', function() use ($app) {
  // do whatever you want
  return 'version 1.2';
});

return $controllers;
```

There may even be a way of doing this using the YML loader and keeping your routes in yml files, but I don't like mixing yml and php in general. Why use two technologies when you can just use one.

### A fancier way

Take a look at [this article](http://gonzalo123.com/2013/03/04/scaling-silex-applications-part-ii-using-routecollection/). His technique is way more elegant than mine, but also more complicated. It's probably better for larger projects. Maybe it will work better for you.

Comment: ok, so you're saying that there is no way to execute the closure directly in the parameter?
Even if not, what's the Silex/Symfony2 way of doing it?

Comment: Edited my answer to include some suggestions on how to do it. Silex doesn't prescribe a single way of doing things, so this is what I've come up with.

Comment: The full Symfony2 way would probably be to use the whole framework and have each route match an action in a controller.